# why doesn't my optical drive read dvds nor bds anymore? only cds

Tags: drivers, hardware, optical

i have installed ubuntu through a CD.

now my optical drive doesn't real DVDs nor BDs anymore.

i'm new to ubuntu. don't know many things. just the basics.

is there a way to either configure it?

should i re-install the drivers? if so, where do i find them and what is the process for reinstalling them?

this is the hardware:   sstcorp Dvdwbd Sn 406ab

i only find help regarding windows. and i can't reinstall windows to solve the problem because of the same issue: can't read dvd

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most commercial DVDs are encrypted with CSS (the Content Scramble System), which attempts to restrict the software that can play a DVD.

By installing the libdvdcss2 package you can play encrypted DVDs.

see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

you can install windows through usb device. see http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

Comment: I GUESS I DIDN'T QUITE EXPLAIN THE PROBLEM PROPERLY.

Comment: UP TO THE POINT WHEN I INSTALLED UBUNTU I HAD NO PROBLEMS WITH IT. NOW IT DOESN'T EVEN READ MY WINDOWS ORIGINAL DVDS NOR ANY OTHER ONE. ONLY CDS.

Comment: I GUESS I'LL HAVE TO DUAL BOOT WITH WIN XP (THE ONLY ONE WHICH FITS INTO A CD). I BELIEVE I NEED TO RECONFIGURE IT OR REINSTALL THE DRIVERS BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS USING UBUNTU. I HAVE TRIED INSTALLING USING USB BUT IT IS A PIRATED COPY (THE ROM DOESNT READ THE ORIGINAL IN ORDER FOR ME TO TRANSFER THE ISO TO THE USB AND EVEN BY DOING THIS THE INSTALLATION ALWAYS STOPS AT 60% WITH AN ERROR MESSAGE. BOTH IN GPT AND MBR.

Comment: THERE MUST BE A WAY TO DIAGNOSE AND SOLVE THE PROBLEM USING UBUNTU. THE EQUIVALENT TO DEVICE MANAGER>PROPERTIES>DRIVER>UPDATE